# Disconnecting HDMI causes vertical split on laptop screen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Whenever i disconnect my HDMI on my Dell Latitude E5550, the laptop screen tries to show both monitors:

[image: As shown here]

I can still move my mouse around and drag windows, but the screen does not refresh.

Not sure if i need to post this on the forums or here. It's been a while since i needed help with Ubuntu

**Edit**: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 running Mate as a desktop environment with Compiz.
Also running kernel 4.5.3, but problems were around when i was on default

So far i've tried to reinstall my drivers and update to latest nvidia drivers. Problem was also around on nouveau.
Found a script called autorandr, as per another askubuntu.com answer(cannot find source anymore unfortunately) 
I attached that script to a shortcut key to press whenever this happens, but that unfortunately changes nothing.

Comment: You might want to add which ubuntu version you're using and what you tried so far.